# how do i add variable value with mysql database column numeric value

Tags: php, mysql, database, addition

I need help to add  `variable value and numeric value` and numeric values are getting from mysql database column?

**Problem**

when i insert `std0001` into the db column then function won't work and move to `std0002` else if there is only number value in the db column then function work and move to `0002,003.0003`?

**Code**

```
$query = "SELECT snum val FROM students";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$new_val = $row['val']+1;
$a='std';
for($i=0; $i <=$new_val; $i++) {

if($new_val == 0) { 
$say=$a.'0'.$i;

} else if($new_val == 1) {
$say=$a.'00'.$i;
}

else
{
$say=$a.'000'.$i;   
}
}
```

**For Example I Want Like**

```
Std00001
Std00002
Std00003
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
So On...
```

Comment: i don't see how you put it in the database. please add this code as well.

Comment: i want to generate series like that... Std00001 Std00002 Std00003 and $a+db column values but problem is when i run that code and function generated Std00001 and then it is stop on .. Std00001 it cannot generated Std00002 and so on with the $a value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your javascript

```
var a = "00001";
    /*store the value "00001" in a variable as you are getting it from a column*/
var b = "std";
var c = parseInt(a) + 1;
alert(b + c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in your code:

1. your query

   ```
   $query = "SELECT MAX(snum) val FROM students";
   ```

   will return only ONE row. So, your script will run only once. That's why you get only Std00001  and then it stops.
2. Now let's say your query indeed retrieved many rows. Here you still fetch only one row using mysql_fetch_assoc. The correct way to retrieve multiple rows is like this:

   ```
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       ... your code here for each row
   }
   ```

   see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php fro examples
3. your for loop is wrong.

   ```
   for($i=1;$i<=$new_val;$i++){
   ```

   $new_val is a string, it must be an integer.

Comment: i want to generate series like that... Std00001 Std00002 Std00003 but based on `$a+db column` values

Comment: you must fix all these issues.